# Commutativity criteria for $C^*$-algebras

Tags: c-star-algebras

If for any $x, y\in A$ a $C^*$-algebra, $0\leq x\leq y\implies x^2\leq y^2$, then it is true that A is commutative ?

It is easy to show that the implication $0\leq x\leq y\implies x^2\leq y^2$ is not true in general, for example in $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R}) $ take for $x$ \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix} and for $y$ \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
Moreover if $A$ is commutative then $y^2-x^2=(y-x)(y+x)$ is a product of two positive elements that commute with each other, thus $y^2-x^2\geq 0$. Indeed, if $a, b\in A^+$ and $ab=ba$ then $(ab)^*=ab$ and $\sigma (ab)=\sigma (a^{1/2}ba^{1/2})\subset [0, \infty [$.

Comment: The result ("Ogasawara's theorem") seems to be proved in "Quantum Measure Theory, Volume 36" p.236. Unfortunately I can't read the whole proof on Google books.

Comment: I think you are giving a pure algebraic proof for the commutative case. But it is obvious since a commutative algebra is C(X) or $C_{0}(X)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed this is known as Ogasawara's theorem, as you pointed out. I like to think of this in terms of representation theory, though **this might be total overkill**. Basically, I can prove the result in three steps:

1. Prove that $B(H)$ contains self-adjoint operators $x,y$ satisfying $0 \leq x \leq y$ and $x^2 \not\leq y^2$ whenever $\dim(H) > 1$. You already took care of that by providing an example.
2. Prove that any strongly dense $C^*$-subalgebra $A\subseteq B(H)$ with $\dim(H) > 1$ contains self-adjoint $x,y$ satisfying $0 \leq x \leq y$ and $x^2 \not\leq y^2$. This is the hardest part. I will get back to this.
3. Use representation theory: an arbitrary $C^*$-algebra $A$ is commutative if and only if every irreducible representation is one-dimensional. (Furthermore, recall that a non-zero  representation $\varphi : A \to B(H)$ is irreducible if and only if $\varphi[A]$ is strongly dense in $B(H)$.) Thus, if $A$ is not commutative, then there exists an irreducible representation $\varphi : A \to B(H)$ with $\dim(H) > 1$. Now by part 2 there are $x,y\in A$ such that $\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(y)$ are self-adjoint and satisfy $0 \leq \varphi(x) \leq \varphi(y)$ as well as $\varphi(x)^2 \not\leq \varphi(y)^2$. Now it is not so hard to see that we may choose $x$ and $y$ self-adjoint and satisfying $0 \leq x \leq y$, though this is not completely trivial either. I'll leave this as an exercise. (Hint: first prove that $\varphi(a^-) = \varphi(a)^-$ holds for all self-adjoint $a\in A$. Then for self-adjoint $a,b\in A$ we have $\varphi(a) \leq \varphi(b)$ if and only if $(b - a)^- \in \ker(\varphi)$ holds.)

I find that most results relating some order-theoretic property of a $C^*$-algebra with its commutativity can be proven this way. (For instance, a similar approach can be used to prove Sherman's theorem: the set $A^{\text{sa}}$ of self-adjoint elements of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is a lattice if and only if $A$ is commutative.) It may not be the easiest proof of Ogasawara's theorem, but at least it doesn't really require any deep insight or clever trick, as it relies on the familiar theorems.

---

Now let's get into step 2 of the solution. There **might well be an easier way to do this** (perhaps even constructively), but here's what I've come up with. We shall use Kaplansky's density theorem as well as the following theorem used in the proof of said theorem:

> **Theorem 1.** If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded continuous function and $\{a_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is a net of self-adjoint operators converging strongly to $a$, then the net $\{f(a_\lambda)\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ converges strongly to $f(a)$.

This has the following very useful consequence:

> **Corollary 2.** If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a (not necessarily bounded) continuous function and $\{a_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is a norm-bounded net of self-adjoint operators converging strongly to $a$, then the net $\{f(a_\lambda)\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ converges strongly to $f(a)$.
>
> **Proof.** There is some $M \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $\sigma(a_\lambda) \subseteq [-M,M]$ holds for all $\lambda\in\Lambda$, as well as $\sigma(a) \subseteq [-M,M]$. Thus, we may cut $f$ off at $x = -M$ and $x = M$ so that $f$ becomes bounded. More precisely, we may define $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
> $$g(x) = \begin{cases} f(-M), & \text{if $x < -M$};\\ f(x), & \text{if $-M \leq x \leq M$};\\ f(M), & \text{if $x > M$}.\end{cases} $$
> Now $f$ and $g$ coincide on $\sigma(a_\lambda)$ for all $\lambda\in\Lambda$, so we have $f(a_\lambda) = g(a_\lambda)$.$\quad\Box$

The version of Kaplansky's density theorem that we need is the following:

> **Theorem 3.** Let $A \subseteq B(H)$ be a $C^*$-subalgebra with strong closure $B$. Then the unit ball of $A^+$ is stongly dense in the unit ball of $B^+$.
>
> **Proof (assuming some other form of Kaplansky's density theorem).** Should this result not be included in the version of Kaplansky's density theorem that you're used to, let $b\in B^+$ be given with $||b|| \leq 1$. By some other form of Kaplansky's density theorem, there exists a net $\{a_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ of self-adjoint elements of $A$ converging strongly to $b$. Consider the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
> $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if $x < 0$}; \\ x, & \text{if $0\leq x \leq 1$} \\ 1, & \text{if $x > 1$}. \end{cases}$$
> By theorem 1 above, the net $\{f(a_\lambda)\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ converges strongly to $f(b)$. But we have $f(b) = b$, and $f(a_\lambda)$ is an element of the unit ball of $A^+$ for all $\lambda\in\Lambda$.$\quad\Box$

Finally, we need the following easy lemmas, which I will not prove.

> **Lemma 4.** The positive cone of $B(H)$ is strongly closed.
>
> **Definition 5.** Let $A$ be any $C^*$-algebra. For any two $a,b\in A^{\text{sa}}$ we define $a \curlyvee b \in A^{\text{sa}}$ by
> $$ a\curlyvee b = \tfrac{1}{2}(a + b + |a - b|). $$
>
> **Lemma 6.**  For any $a,b\in A^{\text{sa}}$, the element $a \curlyvee b$ is an upper bound for $a$ and $b$. Furthermore, if $a$ and $b$ are comparable, then $a\curlyvee b$ is simply the largest of the two.

Now we are ready to prove the result. Suppose that $A \subseteq B(H)$ is a strongly dense $C^*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$, where $\dim(H) > 1$ holds. By part 1 of the general solution, there are self-adjoint $x,y\in B(H)$ satisfying $0 \leq x \leq y$ and $x^2 \not\leq y^2$. By theorem 3, there exist norm-bounded nets $\{a_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ and $\{b_\mu\}_{\mu\in M}$ consisting of positive elements in $A$ that converge strongly to $x$ and $y$, respectively. Without loss of generality, we may assume that these nets are indexed by the same directed set $D$ (take, if necessary, the direct product of $\Lambda$ and $M$). The net $\{a_\lambda - b_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in D}$ is norm-bounded as well, so by corollary 2 we have
$$ \lim_{\lambda\in D} a_\lambda \curlyvee b_\lambda = \lim_{\lambda\in D} \tfrac{1}{2}(a_\lambda + b_\lambda + |a_\lambda - b_\lambda|) = \tfrac{1}{2}(x + y + |x - y|) = x\curlyvee y = y. $$
For convenience, write $c_\lambda = a_\lambda \curlyvee b_\lambda$. The point of this is that we have $0 \leq a_\lambda \leq c_\lambda$ for all $\lambda\in D$. This way we can approximate $x$ and $y$ using two norm-bounded nets $\{a_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in D}$ and $\{c_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in D}$ such that $0 \leq a_\lambda \leq c_\lambda$ holds for all $\lambda\in\Lambda$. Using corollary 2 once more, we find
$$ \lim_{\lambda\in D} c_\lambda^2 - a_\lambda^2 = y^2 - x^2 \notin B(H)^+. $$
Since $B(H)^+$ is strongly closed, there must be at least one $\lambda\in D$ such that $c_\lambda^2 - a_\lambda^2 \not\geq 0$ holds, which proves the claim.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got the general idea, however I can't prove some claims. For example, how do you show that if every irreductible representations are one-dimensional then $A$ is commutative (I have found a proof for the converse) ?

Comment: This is done by proving that the direct sum of all irreducible representations is faithful. This way we obtain a faithful diagonal representation of $A$, so it follows that $A$ is commutative.

Comment: Thank you. I only knew the case of a finite dimensional $C*$-algebra, so I was not sure that I can use this generalized result. I guess this is a straightforward application of Zorn's lemma.
It remains me to prove the last step of the proof : $\varphi(a^-) = \varphi(a)^-$ for all $s.a.$ operators.

Comment: I'm not sure you need Zorn's lemma. For arbitrary $a\in A$ there exists an irreducible representation $\varphi : A \to B(H)$ such that $||\varphi(a)|| = ||a||$ holds. Thus, if we have $ab - ba \neq 0$, then there is an irreducible representation $\varphi : A \to B(H)$ such that $||\varphi(ab - ba)|| = ||ab - ba|| > 0$ holds. Therefore $\varphi(a)$ and $\varphi(b)$ do not commute, so it follows that $\dim(H) > 1$ must hold.
Where exactly did you use Zorn's lemma? I don't think I see the connection... (So this may be a gap in my knowledge.)